# Copy File with contains specific string in a file name vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to copy files which contain "GES" in the file name from a shared location and below is the code I wrote but for some reason its creating entire folder paths from where is being copied. How do I copy only the file instead of Entire folder path.

```
For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(
FileSource,
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*GES*.ini")

    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(foundFile, destination & foundFile)
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this instead (assuming folder is the old folder and newDirectory is the new folder).

You can get the file using the directory filter.

Use the Path.GetFileName to get only the file name portion

Use Path.Combine to get the new full path

```
 For Each file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*GES*.ini")

    Dim shortPath as String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file)
    Dim newPath as String = System.IO.Path.Combine(newDirectory, shortPath)

    ' Copy, 3rd Parameter is Overwrite
    System.IO.File.Copy(file, newPath, True)
 Next
```

Comment: I used the code below. It looks good but the file doesnt get copied .
{

Comment: I used the code below but the file doesnt get copied {Dim folder As New IO.DirectoryInfo(T1Source)

Dim files As IO.FileInfo() = folder.GetFiles()

Dim File As IO.FileInfo


For Each File In files
If File.Name.Contains("GES") And File.Name.EndsWith(".ini") Then
Dim foundfile As String = File.ToString()
Dim GESFile = T1Source & foundfile
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(GESFile, Destination)
End If
Next
}

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim folder As New DirectoryInfo("c:\")
 Dim files As FileInfo() = folder.GetFiles()
 Dim file As FileInfo
 For Each file in files
        If file.Name.StartsWith("GES") And file.Name.EndsWith(".ini") Then
             'do whatever with the file here
        End If
 Next file
```